# "digitalocean" droplet password changing broke the website (502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu))

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, droplet

I have changed the password of the digitalocean droplet then after that the website is not working at all and the api's for the mobile application is not working either.
The website and the apis aren't made by me but by different side,and they built using python-django.

Please i need your help to recover everything as i believe it's a problem with the reset password process i have done.

here is the website : 
http://educationwallets.com/

here is the message i got :

502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Just after a reboot, ssh with eduWallet user and type "supervisord"                      it will start the server.